# Translation of python/numpy "A.argmin(axis=-1)" into an equivalent matlab-expression

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, matrix

I am a newbie in python and got python-code to translate into Matlab for my work. 
I have a specific problem:

I've got a matrix with size for example (rows/columns/3rd dim)  = (3/4/2).

```
A = array([[[1, 56, 0, 6],[5, 9, 10, 3],[50, 51, 59, 64]],[[2, 6, 4, 3],[10, 80, 53, 6],[12, 5, 36, 15]]])
```

For this matrix (and others) I have given the function

```
B = A.argmin(axis=-1)
```

which searches for the index of the minimum in every row. ([numpy.argmin Manual](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html))

B is in this case:

```
B = array([[2, 3, 0],[0, 3, 1]])
```

and of size (rows/columns) = (2/3).

My ame is to convert exactly this into a Matlab-version, so that I get exactly this matrix, but in Matlab ([Min Matlab Manual][2])

```
[~,B] = min(A,[],2)
```

gives me a matrix of size (row/colums/3rd dim) = (3/1/2).
[Matlab Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsExu.png)

The indices of the minimum in each row are the same, if one regard that python starts indexing at 0 and matlab at 1. The problem is the order of the matrix.

How do I get the indeces of the minimum of each row in exact the order as python does it in matlab?

I tried a lot with permute and vertcat, but this didn't work out and in the end it has to work for really big matrices.

I would be pleased, if someone could help me.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please explain a bit more clearly how the results differ. Also, please consider adding the outputs as code instead of pictures.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only problem is that you're taking the wrong dimension in MATLAB. The `axis=-1` in numpy corresponds to the last dimension (so I don't think it looks along each *row* as you've stated in the question), i.e. `min(A,[],3)`:

```
A(1,:,:)=[1 56 0 6; 5 9 10 3; 50 51 59 64];
A(2,:,:)=[2 6 4 3; 10, 80, 53,  6; 12,  5, 36, 15];
[~,B] = min(A,[],3);
```

Resulting in:

```
B =

     3     4     1
     1     4     2
```

Which, as you said, corresponds to the numpy index matrix

```
In [409]: B = A.argmin(axis=-1)

In [410]: B
Out[410]: 
array([[2, 3, 0],
       [0, 3, 1]])
```

Note that if you'd have used `min(A,[],2)` in MATLAB, the resulting matrix would've been of `size` `[2,1,4]`. To get rid of the singleton dimension, you would've had to use `squeeze(B)` to get a 2d array.

Also note that you might have messed up your original matrix. Your numpy `ndarray` is of `shape` `(2,3,4)`, this is the reason why I created the MATLAB counterpart by assigning `3x4` matrices to `A(1,:,:)` and `A(2,:,:)`. I find this a likely source of confusion, since you claim to have ended up with a matrix of size `[2,1,3]` (and not `[2,1,4]`), but then your last two dimensions must have been switched in MATLAB.

Comment: Thanks a lot! One thing I don't understand in switching python and MATLAB is the way you build the matrices. I understand it like this:
In numpy the shape property gives me (z,x,y), i.e. the 3rd dimension and rows (x) and columns (y).
In Matlab I thought I have the notation A(x,y,z), therefore creating the Matrix A as below is not using A(1,:,:) and A(2,:,:), but A(:,:,1) and A(:,:,2). Am I wrong? My Matlab-Output of using A(z,x,y) is not the same matrix as A above...

Comment: @Maren I don't think I understand your approach. You have arrays with 3 indices in both cases. There's no inherent meaning to the indices. One difference might be the order in wich each language *allocates memory* for the array elements, for instance in matlab `A(:,:,1)` will be a contiguous chunk of memory, while `A(1,:,:)` will not. But I would think that by definition, you should get the same array if the `shape` in numpy is the same as the `size` in MATLAB. Could you point me to some source where this index switching of yours comes from?

Comment: @Andras  Index in MATLAB and Python are different.  MATLAB uses the Fortran index order convention, while numpy (by default) uses the C index order convention.  These conventions are opposite, so `A(i, j, k)` in MATLAB is equivalent to `A[k, j, i]` in numpy (by default).  You can define individual numpy arrays to be in Fortran order, but if you don't define the order C order is used.  MATLAB only allows Fortran order.

Comment: @TheBlackCat that would make sense, yes, *reversing* the order; and anyway this just means that the memory allocation is done the other way around. At the end of the day, efficiency arguments aside, you have an array with 3 indices. Isn't that right? If you *translate* from one language to the other (as opposed to interfacing the two), you don't really have to bother about this. Do you? And most importantly: OP said `[x,y,z] <-> [z,x,y]`, which didn't add up to me in any way:)

Comment: Thank you both for helping :)
In my way I tried it out that it its 'A(i,j,k) <-> A[k, i, j]' so that (rows,columns) are always in that order and only additional dimensions are swapped. Isnt it like this?
Nevertheless my question is then how to get exactly the same matrix in Matlab I get with numpy.argmin(axis=-1) although orders are swapped...

Comment: @Maren if the orders are swapped by construction, so e.g. the numpy `A` of shape `(2,3,4)` is matched by the MATLAB `A` of size `[4,2,3]`, then `A.argmin(axis=-1)` in numpy should give the same `(2,3)`-shape matrix as `[~,B]=min(A,[],1); squeeze(B)` in MATLAB: a matrix of size `[2,3]` (with the obvious constant shift of 1 due to different indexing conventions).

Comment: I got it! Thanks a lot!
Finally this way worked out, don't ask why but if I compare python output and matlab output for various matrices, its always the same:

`[~,B] = min(A,[],2);
B = B-1;
B = squeeze(B);
B = permute(B,[2 1 3]);`

First of all, A.argmin(axis=-1) finds the index in each row, missleading that it is axis=-1...strange, but
[~,B] = min(A,[],2) finds the same indices in each row.
squeezing and permuting gives the same as numpy.argmin gives.
Thanks a lot for your help! :) :) :)

Comment: @Maren I'm glad I could help:) Note that after `squeeze` your matrix will be `2d`, so using `permute(...,[2 1 3])` on it would transform it to size `[n1,n2,1]`, but trailing singleton dimensions are automatically removed by MATLAB (because every array has implicitly an infinite number of trailing singleton dimensions).

Comment: Ah well that's true...
It's [2 1 3] because in my work I originally work with 4 dimensions, but in this example its only [2 1], right.
Thanks a lot!